# How to add the checked input box in input text whether onload or onclick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im getting the result now, but what I want is to **Also** get the `checked` input box and put into the input text not just only using `on change` event in jQuery but also on page loads. As you can see, one of the checkboxes below has been checked but not putting into the input text. Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $checks = $(":checkbox");
    $checks.on('change', function() {
        var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        $('#field_results').val(string);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="multiple">
  <input type="text" id="field_results"/><br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>


<div class="multiple">
  <input type="text" id="field_results"/><br>

  <input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" checked>2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">3
</div>
```

Comment: "_put into the input text not just on change_" This is not clear, Could you pls elaborate it a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $checks = $(":checkbox");
  $checks.on('change', setResults);

  function setResults() {
    var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    $('#field_results').val(string);
  }
  setResults();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field_results" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked>2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked>3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set values into input at first, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $checks = $(":checkbox");
  $('#field_results').val(getCheckedValues());
  $checks.on('change', function(){
    $('#field_results').val(getCheckedValues());
   });

});

function getCheckedValues(){
  $checks = $(":checkbox");
  var valuse = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
      return this.value;
   }).get().join(",");
  return valuse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field_results"/><br>

<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked>3<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" checked>5<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it 
You can use .trigger() to set default value

```
$checks.trigger('change');
```

Comment: I cannot use `trigger` because it clicks or check all the checkboxes

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
       $checks = $(":checkbox");
       $checks.on('change', function() {
        var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i,v){
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(",");
        $('#field_results').val(string);
    });
    $checks.trigger('change')
   });